# Reduced Row Echelon form in excel

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering if there was a way I could enter some matrix in excel like ...

1 -1 -1 0

15 5 0 -5

0 -5 10 8

With each number in a cell, and then have excel transform this matrix into reduced row-echelon form.

Comment: I mean where excel itself would use gauss jordan elimination

Comment: No, just as an example. I'd like for excel to transform the matrix automatically in the same way a calculator would

Comment: In the future, questions like these should probably be listed on stackoverflow or a microsoft website, as this is not a math question.  Sorry for the downvote but it isn't appropriate to this website.

Answer (score 1):

The [package matrix](http://digidownload.libero.it/foxes/matrix/MatrixTutorial1.pdf) has a function that performs step-by-step GJ elimination.

Comment: I get an automation error http://digilander.libero.it/foxes/SoftwareDownload.htm when I try to open matrix.xla

Comment: Ouch. I cannot really help you with that. I got that package in my Excel years ago, and I don't even remember how.